# Shopify API - Draft Orders, Mark as Payment Pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I'm creating draft orders using the Shopify API, the API documentation says " the draft order can be paid, set to pending, or paid by credit card; in each case, the draft order is set to completed and an order is created. "

https://help.shopify.com/api/draft-orders

I've been trying alllllll day to set the draft as pending so that Shopify creates a real order and I can do something with that.

If I try and set the status directly I just get this

```
[12] pry(main)> order.status
=> "open"
[13] pry(main)> order.status = 'pending'
=> "pending"
[14] pry(main)> order.status
=> "pending"
[15] pry(main)> order.save
=> true
[16] pry(main)> order.status
=> "open"
[17] pry(main)> order.taxes_included
=> true
[18] pry(main)> order.taxes_included = false
=> false
[19] pry(main)> order.save
=> true
[20] pry(main)> order.taxes_included
=> true
```

I've tried creating a transaction for the DraftOrder but the transaction method doesn't take draft_order_id, only order_id which isn't right.

Permissons on the app are correct and I get the same results from Shopify CLI

Please can someone give some me advice???

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much to everyone who looked at the question.

I've had an official reply from Shopify:

***"Changing the status to complete requires a new endpoint, which is not available right now"***

The Draft Order API is very new, fingers crossed this will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

Order status are

- open - Open orders (default)
- closed - Only closed orders
- any - Any order status

Where as order financial status are

- authorized - Only authorized orders
- pending - Only pending orders
- paid - Only paid orders
- refunded - Show only refunded orders
- voided - Show only voided orders
- any - All authorized, pending, and paid orders (default)

This is with the orders, and i hope it's same with the draft orders. Please try 
`order.financial_status = 'pending'` and this should work.

Comment: No unfortunately draft orders aren't quite the same, I'm guessing because they are drafts they don't have a financial status until they are orders. https://help.shopify.com/api/draft-orders

Comment: I've tried all other keys and none of them are creating a completed draft order, or a new order.